# Git Remote Tracking Branch and Upstream Branch are different

Tags: git

I am not sure how this happened, but if you look at these outputs, emote tracking branch and upstream branch is different. Can somebody explain how could this happen. I know that my pushes are working. What happens when I pull ?

```
PS C:\DigitalOffers\RegPrice> git branch
* dev
  master

PS C:\DigitalOffers\RegPrice> git branch -vv
* dev    b62f88b [origin/master: ahead 52] Price Zone resolution change.
  master 78d5fb6 [origin/master: behind 37] Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/xxxxxxxxx

PS C:\DigitalOffers\RegPrice> git log
commit b62f88b137fa067f7d0f75ec35fb8b63fc885f50 (HEAD -> dev, origin/dev)

PS C:\DigitalOffers\RegPrice> cat .git/config
[core]
    symlinks = false
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/XXXXXX
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
    rebase = false
[branch "dev"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
    rebase = false
[branch "origin/dev"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
    rebase = false
[http "https://github.com"]
    sslVerify = false
[gui]
    wmstate = zoomed
    geometry = 584x210+234+234 469 196

PS C:\DigitalOffers\RegPrice> git push
fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match
the name of your current branch.  To push to the upstream branch
on the remote, use

    git push origin HEAD:master

To push to the branch of the same name on the remote, use

    git push origin HEAD

To choose either option permanently, see push.default in 'git help config'.
```

One more point I want add is- these refs were done by EGit in eclipse.

Comment: are you sure your `git push` is working for `dev` branch?

Comment: Yes, that is what git log says. it is sending to dev. Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Why not set the upstream of dev to dev?

Comment: I am just trying to understand what is happening here. How is the push working. Working perfectly, sending changes to dev in github.

Comment: When you push, what command do you actually give? Do you know? (You might not if you’re using an IDE like Sourcetree.)

Comment: Correct. I do not know. I was just clicking Stage->Commit->Push to Upstream in eclipse. I will do those from command line and let you know what happens.

Comment: I guess git push sums it all. Added more code above...

Comment: Yes, that is what I would expect to see when you say plain `git push`. So you see, your claim that `git push` is working is _false_. Well, it is working correctly, but that means it is refusing to push, which is just what I would expect when the upstream branch name does not match the current branch name. So the problem is solved. Eclipse is giving _explicit_ instructions about how to push. That's why it works. Do you see? Okay, now please just fix the upstream of `dev` to point to `dev` as I suggested earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A branch whose upstream has a different name is broken. That's the situation you are in; your `dev` branch has origin's `master` as its upstream. To fix it, repoint the `dev` branch's upstream so that it is origin's `dev` instead.

The reason this situation has not destroyed your ability to push is that Eclipse is giving *explicit* instructions about what to do, i.e. what branch to push to. It has been saving you. But it is better to save yourself by getting the branch's configuration right.

Comment: Thank you @matt. I tried to vote it but looks like I need 15 reputations minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the configuration. Here is the new configuration and new push

```
PS C:\DigitalOffers\RegPrice> git branch -vv
* dev    946f432 [origin/dev: ahead 1] Added app description in readme.md
master 78d5fb6 [origin/master: behind 37] Merge branch 'master' of 
https://github.com/XXXXXX

PS C:\DigitalOffers\RegPrice> cat .git/config
[core]
    symlinks = false
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/XXXXXXX
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
    rebase = false
[branch "dev"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/dev
    rebase = false
[branch "origin/dev"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/dev
    rebase = false
[http "https://github.com"]
    sslVerify = false
[gui]
    wmstate = zoomed
    geometry = 584x210+234+234 469 196

PS C:\DigitalOffers\RegPrice> git push
Username for 'https://github.com': 
Password for 'https://@github.com':
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 349 bytes | 43.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), completed with 1 local object.
To https://github.com/XXXXX
    b62f88b..946f432  dev -> dev
```